# Detect which Taskbar button was clicked (identify target window)

Tags: onclick, autohotkey, detection, double-click, taskbar

I am trying to figure out how to detect which Taskbar button was clicked. Specifically, I want to write a script that makes it possible to maximize a window by double-clicking its Taskbar button. That requires knowing which Taskbar button was clicked, which I am having a difficult time finding any leads on.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: You'll have to use [WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx) through `DllCall` and maybe `RegisterCallback` *a lot*. I suggest searching AHK forums for similar scripts to get the idea how it's done because hacking Windows Explorer functionality isn't trivial.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888422/find-cordinates-of-pinned-taskbar-shorcuts

Answer (score 1):

That's a though one I have to admit. I can't offer you a best practice solution, but here is a little work around, maybe that enough for your purposes:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
~LButton:: 
    If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<400) and (A_PriorHotkey="~LButton") {
        WinGetPos, taskBarX, taskBarY, taskBarW, taskBarH, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
        MouseGetPos, mouseX, mouseY
        If (mouseX >= taskBarX && mouseY >= taskBarY && mouseX <= taskBarX+taskBarW && mouseY <= taskBarY+taskBarH)
            OnDoubleClickTaskbar()
    }
Return

OnDoubleClickTaskbar() {
    ;WinWaitNotActive, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    Sleep, 200
    WinMaximize, A
}
```

Tested on Windows 8.1.